# can't find content length when creating a mjpeg streaming in urllib

Tags: python, streaming, urllib

I am using urllib to receive a streaming from a online camera, which is 
http://cemrcam1.cemr.wvu.edu/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480, however when connecting to the stream, it throws out a error saying:

```
DEBUG:root:Connecting to stream...
DEBUG:root:Content length field not found
```

how would I solve this issue?

```
def video_feed():

    # URL to open
    LINK = 'http://cemrcam1.cemr.wvu.edu/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480'

    error_image = 'error_image.jpg'

    # Connect to stream
    try:
        logging.debug("Connecting to stream...")
        stream = urllib.urlopen(LINK)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.debug("Failed to connect to stream: " + str(ex))
        return send_file(error_image, mimetype="image/jpeg")

    # Check if data looks like an mjpeg stream
    if 'multipart/x-mixed-replace' not in stream.info()["content-type"]:
        logging.debug("'%s' did not produce an mjpeg stream" % LINK)
        return send_file(error_image, mimetype="image/jpeg")

    # Figure out boundary string
    try:
        boundary = [ x[9:] for x in stream.info()["content-type"].split(';') if 'boundary' in x ][0]
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.debug("Failed to figure out boundary string: " + str(ex))
        return send_file(error_image, mimetype="image/jpeg")

    # Start returning data
    return Response(gen(stream, error_image, boundary), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=%s' % boundary)

def gen(stream, error_image, boundary):
    # Add headers to the error
    with open(error_image, 'rb') as f:
        error_with_headers = b'--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + f.read() + b'\r\n'

    while True:
        content_length_found = False

        # Start with blank data var
        data = ''

        # Read first several lines, looking for content length line
        for line in range(10):
            data += stream.readline()

            if 'Content-Length' in data:
                content_length_found = True
                break

        if content_length_found:
            # Figure out the content length
            try:
                content_length = int(data.splitlines()[-1].rstrip().split()[-1])
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                raise
            except Exception as ex:
                logging.debug("Failed to parse the content length line")
                yield error_with_headers
                raise StopIteration

            logging.debug("Content_Length: %d" % content_length)
        else:
            # Unable to figure out content length
            logging.debug("Content length field not found")
            yield error_with_headers
            raise StopIteration

        # Read the line before the jpeg
        data += stream.readline()

        # Read the jpeg
        data += stream.read(content_length)

        # Return the jpeg
        yield data
```

Comment: That MJPEG stream has no `Content-Length`, it's a live feed... What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, i am trying to get this live feed

Comment: What do you mean by "get"?

Comment: fetch the content of latest image in this live feed

Comment: Your code essentially proxies the original stream after trying to parse it. It doesn't modify it in any way. What is your goal?

Comment: how would i parse it in the right way

Comment: Before you try parsing it, do you have a reason to parse it? What is `video_feed` supposed to do with the content stored in `URL`? Can you not just return a redirect to `URL`?

Comment: video_feed is actually a route in the flask,  it has @video_feed, so visiting  ip/video_feed will return the image content

Comment: Why can't you just do `@app.route('/video_feed') def video_feed(): return redirect("http://cemrcam1.cemr.wvu.edu/nphMotionJpeg?resolution=640x480")`?

Comment: yes, it can show the content on the browser, but I need to save the image and importantly get the latest image from the updated timestamp